# list_display in admin behave nothing

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

This is my github repo [Inout](https://github.com/rajasimon/inout). I am learning django and i worked Very very simple django registration & login system.

**My question is:**

How to list all the `usernames` in `admin` using `list_display`. But nothing display in admin panel. May i know why ?

**Inside my working code:**

```
# models.py
username = models.OneToOneField(User)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


# admin.py
class SignupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['username']
admin.site.register(Signup, SignupAdmin)
```

**Information for you Reference :**

if i am using  `list_filter` in admin i can see all the username in the filter panel

Then if i am accessing this page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/system/signup/`

```
Select signup to change
0 signups
```

And also if i am accessing this page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/frontend/profile/add/` i can see the **drop down** of `username` shows all the username i registered before.

[image]

What i `missing` ? or can somebody `clone` my `repo` and see yourself.

Comment: what do you mean by not working fine. What happens when you use `list_filter` ?

Comment: list_dislay should be a tuple. change list_display = ['username'] to list_display = ('username',)

Comment: if i am changing to () then the error is 'SignupAdmin.list_display' must be a list or tuple.

Comment: @gmfreak - `list_display` can be a list or tuple.  @user3895077 `list_display = ('username',)` will work as `('username',)` is a tuple of length 1, but `list_display = ('username')` will not work as in python the parentheses will be ignored and that is equivalent to `list_display = 'username'`.  See for example: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax

Comment: @karthikr if i am using `list_filter`.. I can see the list of `username` displaying in filter panel

Comment: @drjimbob yes.. you are correct. I tried with `(list_filter,)` that's working but sadly `list_display` not working ...

Comment: @karthikr what should i do now ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's not working correctly?  `list_display` is supposed to take a tuple/list of fields and then display those fields as columns of the main table like in the picture shown below [taken from the django admin documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display), where each entry in the main table has a username, email address, first name, last name, staff status.  This would be created by

```
 list_display = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff']
```

in a ModelAdmin for the built in User model (taken from `django.contrib.auth.models`).  The side-column on the right side (with the label "Filter") is populated only when you define fields under `list_filter`.

Note if you only defined one field, and your model has a `__unicode__` function that returns the username, you will not see a significant difference with just adding `list_display = ('username',)`.  I suggest you try `list_display = ('username', 'first_name',)`.  In this case, for every `SignUp` you will see two columns in the main table -- one with the `username` and one with the `first_name`.

[image: List Display Example]

---

**EDIT**

You have two errors.

First, you don't seem to have created any `SignUp` objects anywhere.  Before the admin change list will display any entries, you must create some entries.

Second, your `__unicode__` method of your SignUp model refers to non-existent fields (self.user is never defined -- in your SignUp class you used `username = models.OneToOneField(User)`
, hence you refer to it as `username`) and furthermore it doesn't return a unicode string as required.

Try:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    if self.username:
        return unicode(self.username)
```

then create some SignUp and then it will work.  Again, the list_display part was working perfectly.

Comment: @user3895077 - If you want further help, please try to communicate why you believe that it is not working.  Can you paste a screenshot?  Or an error message?  Are there any `SignUp` objects defined?